# Determine which value represents which direction in a path

Tags: code-golf

**Important edit: Earlier, there was an incorrect value in Example 1.  It has been fixed.**

You are given a two-dimensional array in which each cell contains one of four values.

Examples:

```
1 2 2 2 2 1        @ . .        X X V
1 3 1 4 1 4        e . @        I C V
2 3 1 3 4 2        H H @        X I V
1 4 4 2 1 3                     V C C
2 2 2 3 2 3                     X X X
```

The four values represent directional arrows (up, down, left, and right), although you don't know which value represents which direction.

The directional arrows form an unbroken path that includes every cell in the array, although you don't know where the start or end points are.

Write some code that determines which direction each of the four values represents and where the start and end points are.

An acceptable return value for an array that contains the values A, B, C, and D would be something like:

```
{ up: A, down: C, left: D, right: B, start: [2, 0], end: [4, 2] }
```

<del>Because you can traverse the path both ways (from start to end and from end to start), there will always be more than one correct solution, and there might be more than two.</del>  Assume that the inputs you receive (as in the above examples) always have at least one correct solution.  In cases where there is more than one correct solution, returning just one of the correct solutions is sufficient.

Shortest code wins.  I'll pick the winner after 7 days or 24 hours without a new submission, whichever comes first.

I'm including solutions to the examples above, but I'd encourage you to only check them once you've written your code:

One:

> { up: 3, down: 1, left: 4, right: 2, start: [0,0], end: [2,5] }

Two:

> { up: '@', down: 'e', left: '.', right: 'H', start: [1,1], end: [0,0] }

Three:

> { up: 'I', down: 'V', left: 'C', right: 'X', start: [0,2], end: [4,2] }

Comment: "you can traverse the path both ways" -- if the directions are absolute, not relative, this is not true. Are the directions absolute, or relative? Also, are the start and end known to be outside the array?

Comment: @JanDvorak The start and end points are cells within the array.  As for the directions, assume they always indicate movement into an adjacent cell (north, south, east, or west).

Comment: In which case it's not possible to traverse a path backwards. I can't see any guarantee there will always be more than one solution.

Comment: I assume we can do anything at all if there's no solution?

Comment: @JanDvorak I've updated the description to address the questions you've raised.

Comment: Could you please include the answers for the three examples?

Comment: If we "assume they always indicate movement into an adjacent cell", is your second example still valid?  I may be missing something but it seems like @ could not be any of the four directions without going "out of bounds".

Comment: @NickSarabyn  Thanks for that catch.  I neglected to consider the end point.  The final cell in the path may violate the "always point to an adjacent cell" rule.  Obviously, once you've reached the final cell, you will not go any further, so it doesn't matter in which direction it's pointing.  But I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: Example 1 has no solution.

Comment: The solutions ending points have the coordinates swapped

Answer (score 6):

### C#

EDIT: Fixed a division and formatting. And added the helper class.

This is the golfed code, 807 chars

```
class M{public int c,x,y,u;}
void G(string[] z){
M K;int[]x={0,0,-1,1},y={-1,1,0,0},I={0,0,0,0};
string[]T={"Up","Down","Left","Right"};
int X,Y,R,n=0,H=z.Length,W=z[0].Length;W-=W/2;var D= string.Join(" ", z).Where(c=>c!=' ').Select(c=>new M(){c=c,x=n%W,y=n++/W}).ToList();n=0;var S=D.GroupBy(k=>k.c).ToDictionary(k=>k.Key,k =>n++);
for(;I[0]<4;I[0]++)for(I[1]=0;I[1]<4;I[1]++)for(I[2]=0;I[2]<4;I[2]++)for(I[3]=0;I[3]<4;I[3]++){
if ((1<<I[0]|1<<I[1]|1<<I[2]|1<<I[3])!=15)continue;
foreach (var Q in D){D.ForEach(p=>p.u=-1);R=1;K=Q;j:if((X=K.x+x[n=I[S[K.c]]])>=0&&X<W&&(Y=K.y+y[n])>=0&&Y<H&&(K=D[X+Y*W]).u<0){
K.u=1;if(++R==D.Count){Console.WriteLine("{4} Start({0}:{1}) End({2}:{3})",Q.x,Q.y,K.x,K.y,string.Join(", ",S.Select(k=>string.Format("{1}: '{0}'",(char)k.Key,T[I[k.Value]])).ToArray()));return;}goto j;}}}
}
```

Results for the three test cases:

> Down: '1', Right: '2', Up: '3', Left: '4' Start(0:0) End(5:2)
>   Up: '@', Left: '.', Down: 'e', Right: 'H' Start(1:1) End(0:0)
>   Right: 'X', Down: 'V', Up: 'I', Left: 'C' Start(0:2) End(2:4)

This is the raw code without "golf", almost 4,000 characters:

```
class Program
{
    static string[] input1 =  { "1 2 2 2 2 1",
               "1 3 4 4 1 4",       
               "2 3 1 3 4 2",
               "1 4 4 2 1 3",       
               "2 2 2 3 2 3"};

    static string[] input2 =  { "@ . .",
                                "e . @",       
                                "H H @",
               };

    static string[] input3 =  { "0 0 1",
                                "0 0 1",       
                                "3 2 2",
               };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Resolve(input1);
        Resolve(input2);
        Resolve(input3);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    class N { public int c; public int x, y, i, u; }

    static void Resolve(string[] input)
    {
        int[] ox = { -1, 1, 0, 0 }, oy = { 0, 0, -1, 1 }, I = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        string[] TXT = { "Left", "Right", "Up", "Down" };
        int X, Y, R, n = 0, H = input.Length, W = input[0].Length;
        W -= W / 2;
        N K = null;
        var data = string.Join(" ", input).Where(c => c != ' ').Select(c => new N() { c = c, x = (n % W), y = (n / W), i = n++, u = -1 }).ToList();
        n = 0;
       var S = data.GroupBy(k => k.c).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => n++);

        for (; I[0] < 4; I[0]++)
            for (I[1] = 0; I[1] < 4; I[1]++)
                for (I[2] = 0; I[2] < 4; I[2]++)
                    for (I[3] = 0; I[3] < 4; I[3]++)
                    {
                        if (((1 << I[0]) | (1 << I[1]) | (1 << I[2]) | (1 << I[3])) != 15) continue;
                        foreach(var Q in data)
                        {
                            data.ForEach(p => p.u = -1);
                            R = 0;
                            K = Q;
                            while (K != null)
                            {
                                n = I[S[K.c]];
                                X = K.x + ox[n];
                                Y = K.y + oy[n];
                                if (X >= 0 && X < W && Y >= 0 && Y < H)
                                {
                                    n = X + Y * W;
                                    if (data[n].u < 0)
                                    {
                                         data[n].u = K.i;
                                         K = data[n];
                                        R++;
                                        if (R == data.Count - 1)
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine();
                                            Console.WriteLine("Start({0}:{1}) End({2}:{3})", Q.x, Q.y, K.x, K.y);
                                            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", S.Select(k => string.Format("'{0}': {1}", (char)k.Key, TXT[I[k.Value]])).ToArray()));
                                            Action<N> Write = null;
                                            Write = (k) =>
                                             {
                                                 if (k.u != -1)
                                                 {
                                                     Write(data[k.u]);
                                                 }
                                                 Console.Write(string.Format("({0}:{1}){2}", k.x, k.y, k == K ? "\n" : " => "));
                                             };

                                            Write(K);
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                }
                                K = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
        Console.WriteLine("Solution not found");
    }
 }
}
```

These are the results for the three examples:

> Solution not found
>
> Start(1:1) End(0:0) '@': Up, '.': Left, 'e': Down, 'H': Right
>
> (1:1) => (0:1) => (0:2) => (1:2) => (2:2) => (2:1) => (2:0) => (1:0) => (0:0)
>
> Start(0:0) End(1:1) '0': Right, '1': Down, '3': Up, '2': Left
>
> (0:0) => (1:0) => (2:0) => (2:1) => (2:2) => (1:2) => (0:2) => (0:1) => (1:1)

Comment: You may want to golf your code, as this is a code-golf competition.

Comment: I'm doing it :)

Comment: Okay, no rush :) It's just that some people see a new user without golfed code and tend to downvote.

Comment: It's my first time... but I advise that is not golfed yet... although I think I won't beat matemathica code... :)

Comment: Any answer to this question requires skill. +1

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica 278

Spaces added for "clarity"

```
k@l_ := (s = #~Join~-# &@{{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
         f@r_ := Flatten[MapIndexed[#2 -> #2 + (#1 /. r) &, l, {2}], 1];
         g     = Subgraph[#, t = Tuples@Range@Dimensions@l] & /@ 
                       Graph /@ f /@ (r = Thread[# -> s] & /@ Permutations[Union @@ l]);
        {t[[#]] & /@ Ordering[Tr /@ IncidenceMatrix@g[[#]]][[{1, -1}]], r[[#]]} & @@@ 
                                                                 Position[PathGraphQ /@ g, True])
```

Session & Output:

```
 l = l1 = {{1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4}, {2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2}, 
            {1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3}}; ;
 k@l1
 {{{{1, 1}, {3, 6}}, 
    {1 -> {1, 0}, 2 -> {0, 1}, 3 -> {-1, 0},  4 -> {0, -1}}}}
```

Which is the start Vertex, End Vertex and the transition rules associated with each symbol.

Here is the complementary code to show the oriented graph:

```
sol = sg[[Position[PathGraphQ /@ sg, True][[1, 1]]]];
Framed@Graph[
  VertexList@sol,
  EdgeList@sol,
  VertexCoordinates -> VertexList@sol /. {x_, y_} :> {y, -x},
  VertexLabels -> MapThread[Rule, {VertexList@sol, Flatten@l}], 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData["FilledArcArrow", "ArrowSize" -> 0.03],
  ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica (151)

```
L = {{1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4}, {2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2}, 
   {1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3}};

PathGraphQ@#~If~Print@{TopologicalSort[#]〚{1,-2}〛,r}&@
Graph@Flatten@MapIndexed[#2->#2+(#/.r)&,L,{2}]~Do~{r,
Thread[Union@@L->#]&/@{-1,0,1}~Tuples~{4,2}}
```

It returns start point, end point, and transition rules. The first index is row, the second is column

```
{{{1,1},{3,6}},{1->{1,0},2->{0,1},3->{-1,0},4->{0,-1}}}
```

Note that my code works even with `{-1,0,1}~Tuples~{4,2}`. For speeding up you can use `Permutations@{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

## APL (207)

I couldn't make it shorter than Mathematica, because I couldn't reason in terms of TopologicalSort and such. Smarter people are welcome to squeeze it further.

**Golfed:**

```
{u←∪,t←⍵⋄q r←↑(0≠+/¨r)/⊂[2]p,⍪r←{m←,⍵[u⍳t]⋄v r←⊂[1]⊃{{(↑⍴∪⍵),⊂(↑⍵)(↑⌽⍵)}n↑{3::⍬⋄i←↑⌽⍵⋄⍵,i+i⌷m}⍣n,⍵}¨⍳n←↑⍴,t⋄↑(v=n)/r}¨p←⊂[2]{1≥⍴⍵:⊃,↓⍵⋄⊃⍪/⍵,∘∇¨⍵∘~¨⍵}d←¯1 1,¯1 1×c←¯1↑⍴t⋄⊃('←→↑↓',¨u[q⍳d]),{1+(⌊⍵÷c)(c|⍵)}¨r-1}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
D←{⎕ML ⎕IO←3 1
    pmat←{1≥⍴⍵:⊃,↓⍵⋄⊃⍪/⍵,∘∇¨⍵∘~¨⍵}   ⍝ utility: permutations of the given vector
    u←∪,t←⍵                    ⍝ the 4 unique symbols in t←⍵
    n←↑⍴,t                     ⍝ number of elements in t
    d←¯1 1,¯1 1×c←¯1↑⍴t        ⍝ the four ∆i (+1, -1, +cols, -cols)
    p←⊂[2]pmat d               ⍝ list of permutations of the four ∆i
    r←{                        ⍝ for each permutation ⍵∊p (=interpretation of the 4 symbols)
        m←,⍵[u⍳t]              ⍝ (ravelled) t-shaped matrix of ∆i, using interpretation ⍵
        v r←⊂[1]⊃{             ⍝ for each starting index ⍵∊⍳n
            v←n↑{              ⍝ trail of visited cells after n steps 
                3::⍬           ⍝ if index out of bounds return empty list
                i←↑⌽⍵          ⍝ take last visited index
                ⍵,i+i⌷m        ⍝ follow the directions and add it to the list
            }⍣n,⍵
            (↑⍴∪v),⊂(↑v),↑⌽v   ⍝ number of unique cells, plus start/end indices
        }¨⍳n
        ↑(v=n)/r               ⍝ 1st couple of start/end indices to visit all cells (if any)
    }¨p
    q r←↑(0≠+/¨r)/⊂[2]p,⍪r     ⍝ select first perm. and start/end indices to visit all cells
    ⊃('←→↑↓',¨u[q⍳d]),{1+(⌊⍵÷c)(c|⍵)}¨r-1   ⍝ return char mapping and start/end indices
}
```

**Examples:**

(Indices start at 1)

```
     D⊃'122221' '131414' '231342' '144213' '222323'
 ←  4 
 →  2 
 ↑  3 
 ↓  1 
 1  1 
 3  6 
     D⊃'@..' 'e.@' 'HH@'
 ←  . 
 →  H 
 ↑  @ 
 ↓  e 
 2  2 
 1  1 
     D⊃'XXV' 'ICV' 'XIV' 'VCC' 'XXX'
 ←  C 
 →  X 
 ↑  I 
 ↓  V 
 3  1 
 5  3
```